# using android pre build tensorflow tflight model from android example in python code

Tags: python, android, tensorflow, text-classification

I recently downloaded an android demo app for text classification made by TensorFlow and this is the GitHub link [android GitHub demo](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/text_classification/android)

and within that app it has 2 mode to predict if the text is positive or negative using (AverageWordVec / MobileBERT ) but MobileBERT accuracy is way better

Now i tried to search for alternative but using python but i couldnt find anything using the same mode or even close to the same accurecy.

Is there away to use `mobilebert.tflite` file in python and get the same prediction?
Would be very appreciated if someone can give me example code to run that file in python

[image: tensorflow]

---

**UPDATES**

when im using tokenizer method it runs but im getting this output:

```
    2022-11-15 15:22:40.048025: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 AVX512F FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2022-11-15 15:22:40.177014: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.11.0'; dlerror: libcudart.so.11.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2022-11-15 15:22:40.177060: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
2022-11-15 15:22:40.208395: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:2981] Unable to register cuBLAS factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuBLAS when one has already been registered
2022-11-15 15:22:40.831937: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer.so.7'; dlerror: libnvinfer.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2022-11-15 15:22:40.832028: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer_plugin.so.7'; dlerror: libnvinfer_plugin.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2022-11-15 15:22:40.832041: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Cannot dlopen some TensorRT libraries. If you would like to use Nvidia GPU with TensorRT, please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly.
2022-11-15 15:22:41.897720: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcuda.so.1'; dlerror: libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2022-11-15 15:22:41.897765: W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:263] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)
2022-11-15 15:22:41.897783: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:156] kernel driver does not appear to be running on this host (Android-CI-CD): /proc/driver/nvidia/version does not exist
2022-11-15 15:22:41.898114: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 AVX512F FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
INFO: Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU.
```

and when i use tflite_support.task Method im getting this output

```
2022-11-15 15:25:30.210277: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 AVX512F FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2022-11-15 15:25:30.342254: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.11.0'; dlerror: libcudart.so.11.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2022-11-15 15:25:30.342295: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
2022-11-15 15:25:30.372550: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:2981] Unable to register cuBLAS factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuBLAS when one has already been registered
2022-11-15 15:25:30.990440: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer.so.7'; dlerror: libnvinfer.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2022-11-15 15:25:30.990522: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer_plugin.so.7'; dlerror: libnvinfer_plugin.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2022-11-15 15:25:30.990532: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Cannot dlopen some TensorRT libraries. If you would like to use Nvidia GPU with TensorRT, please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly.
INFO: Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: See the official documentation, [TensorFlow Lite runtime](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/python) or [tf.lite.Interpreter](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/lite/Interpreter).

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1:** You can use `tflite-support` by installing `pip install tflite-support`.

```
from tflite_support.task import text
classifier = text.BertNLClassifier.create_from_file('mobilebert.tflite')
classifier.classify('go to hell')

#Output:
[Classifications(categories=[Category(index=0, score=0.9992809891700745, display_name='', category_name='negative'), Category(index=0, score=0.0007190419128164649, display_name='', category_name='positive')], head_index=0, head_name='')])
```

**Method 2**:

Get the tokenizers and set up inference:

```
from transformers import MobileBertTokenizer #pip install transformers

tokenizer = MobileBertTokenizer.from_pretrained("google/mobilebert-uncased")

inputs = tokenizer('go to hell!', return_tensors="tf")

# Load TFLite model and allocate tensors.
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path="mobilebert.tflite")

# Get input and output tensors.
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

interpreter.allocate_tensors()
```

Run inference:

```
#set input
input_shape = input_details[0]['shape']
word_ids = tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(inputs['input_ids'], maxlen=128, padding='post')
input_type_ids =  tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(inputs['token_type_ids'], maxlen=128, padding='post')
mask = tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(inputs['attention_mask'], maxlen=128, padding='post')

interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], word_ids)
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[1]['index'], input_type_ids)
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[2]['index'], mask)

# run the inference
interpreter.invoke()

#output
interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
```

Comment: i did try that but how to set the input as string ? for example i want to test "this movie is good" where to add it

Comment: you should use the `tokenizer` that takes text and converts to `word_ids`

Comment: can you please give example of tokinzer

Comment: getting error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tflite_support.task'
 and when i run pip install tflite-support it says Requirement already satisfied

Comment: i found out maybe the reason is i have tflite-support-0.3.1 while latest version is 0.4.3 but when i try to uninstall and install using pip it always install the same version also when i run pip install tflite-support --upgrade it says i have the latest version

Comment: Not sure about your installation problem, but added tokenizer code.

Comment: i managed to fix the tflite-support it seems like it require min python version 3.7 i had 3.6, also i updated the question with last results

Comment: You don't have proper tensorflow installed. Install tensorflow and transformers for method 2 to work.

Comment: i have transformers version 4.24.0 and tensorflow version 2.10.0 which versions should i get

Comment: Problem is not the versions, your installations doesnt seem to work- Check the error - "Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.11.0'. You should not get these.  Use Google Colab to check, meanwhile reinstall tensorflow.

Comment: can tensorflow run on virtual machine doesn't have nividia card or GPU